# Bundling Chromium (or Chrome) as stand-alone and without OS UI (chromeless)

Tags: google-chrome, bundle, native, chromeless

I'm working on a new project and it's based on Python + Web.py for the back-end, and for the front-end I'm using HTML/JS.

I want to be able to bundle with my Python app a stand-alone Chrome (or Chromium) so that I will not need to rely on the users' browser and be able to develop directly for the latest Chromium, and after the installation I will basically create an "--app=" shortcut to my bundled Chromeium - Is it possible?

The second thing that I'm interested in is launching Chrome without the native UI (the native window), sort of like how Adobe Air does it, but without the Adobe Air (I understand that Air no longer supports Linux).

I'm a Python and a Chromium newbie, so links and reading material to any related topic would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I have been considering something similar with flask and the python webkit gtk bindings, but using python as the OS entrypoint. Perhaps one could modify the chrome source to link to a python runtime and library?